# How to redirect to a page after loggin in with facebook?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook php-sdk for allowing the users to login to my website through facebook.
The login function works properly.But After I login I want the user to get redirected to my website.Does anyone knows where to change the redirect url??I would had liked to post the code of for it here but its not just one file plus the code is way way to long..I have downloaded the example form web and used.If i have to use "header()" for relocating I don't know where to write..I want to know where can i write the code for redirecting

I am using this example 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk
In the above link navigate to "test/test.php" there too many functions here which are being called and all of them has REDIRECT_URI option..I am confused to where do i need to change the the REDIRECT_URI..And is tests.php is the place to change the URL??If Not then where i have to change??

Comment: Please provide a link to the example you used.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I will take this tutorial as an example since there is no code in your question.

http://cacovsky.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/login-with-facebook-php-sdk-a-tutorial/

If you visit this page or another tutorial, which I assume you have done before, you will be able to search the site for the term "header".

```
header('Location: http://localhost/fb/index.php');
```

This line provides the information to which site in your application the Facebook Login will redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno how often this was asked now ...

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use.
If you use FB login button use below code

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true
  ));

<fb:login-button scope="email,friends_likes" onlogin='window.location="{here your full URL after login}";'>Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

If you use signin URL using the FB API, you can use as

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true
  ));

  $params = array(
  'scope' => 'email, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => '{here your full URL after login }'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Comment: thanks for reply..in the question i have shared the link.In that link navigate to "test/test.php" there too many functions here which are being called and all of them has REDIRECT_URI option..I am confused to where do i need to change the the REDIRECT_URI

Comment: If its login and redirect after that then I would suggest to use simple FB login button or getLoginURL where you need to provide the redirect URI. But make sure that the URI is something like www.domain.com/{some file}, dont use as just test.php,and BTW dont change anything inside SRC folder from your link, you need to include them in you page and write your own login part using the API